# PHP not working on fresh install

Tags: ubuntu, php

Ok so i just installed apache2 and php5 following along with this tutorial

```
http://www.socialblogr.com/2010/08/how-to-install-php-monggodb-monggo-driver-on-linux-ubuntu.html
```

But php isn't working, when i try to view a .php file i just the the entire code, although php is installed and i restarted the server

```
< ?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: a very related question: http://superuser.com/questions/425181/php-code-is-returned-instead-of-executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have checked that your apache conf file is loading the module? You should have a line something like this:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache22/libphp5.so
```

The paths may be different on your machine. But often package installers will add the correct line, but leave it commented out.

Comment: just checked /etc/apache2/apache2.conf nothing about a php5_module. Should i add it myself ?Whats the exact line

Comment: exact line depends on where you installed the php module. Have a look at the rest of the LoadModule lines and check if you installed the the libphp5.so in the same place. The above line has a relative path (relative to the ServerRoot in your apache config file. You can also specify an absolute path if it's somewhere else. But handiest to keep them all together usually.

Comment: andrei@ubuntu:~$ sudo a2enmod php5
Module php5 already enabled

Comment: Have you an AddType line?

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

Answer (score -1):

enable php short code from **php.ini**

By default short codes are not enabled

or use this `<?php` instead of this `<?`

also execute: `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt` for ubuntu users