# PHP code is returned instead of executed

Tags: php, localhost, apache-http-server

I have L-Ubuntu 11.04. I've installed Apache2 and I'm trying to simulate a server on my local file system by navigating to `localhost` in the browser.

The problem is that I can't seem to get php to execute when on localhost. The PHP code is simply printed in the browser (instead of being executed and the result being printed).

- `libapache2-mod-php5` is installed and the latest version.
- The Apache module php5 is enabled.

How can I get PHP to run on localhost?

Comment: 1. *The problem is [...] when on localhost.* Does that mean it works from elsewhere? 2. *[...] I can't seem to get php to execute [...]* What exactly happens?

Comment: 1. Yeah it works when I have that very folder structure on the server. But if I copy the website to my local computer and put it into the localhost... no php. 2. What happends is that the php code simply gets printed directly instead of being interpreted.

Comment: Try copying the files `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.*` from your server to your home computer and restart `apache2`. Just to be sure, make backup copies first.

Comment: It's a rented server space and sadly I don't have access to that folder.

Comment: Do your php files have a non-standard extension? Did you copy all hidden files (specifically, `.htaccess`). Did you check the downloaded files in the (remote) case they got modified somehow by downloading?

Comment: what im trying to run exactly now is not even a php file at all, its an .html file, and it ends with .html. I copied .htaccess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3449/discussion-between-dennis-and-hermann-ingjaldsson)

Comment: a very related question: http://superuser.com/questions/290964/php-not-working-on-fresh-install

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf` controls which files Apache recognizes as php scripts (based on their extensions).

Be default (in PHP 5.3.2), the file contains the following code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

This affects files with the following extensions:

- `.php`
- `.php3`
- `.phtml`

From [our discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3449/discussion-between-dennis-and-hermann-ingjaldsson), I know that your files have a `html` extension. The server was configured to treat `.html` files as php files, but your home computer is not. That leaves you with two options:

1. Rename your `.html` files that contain php code to one of the above extensions.
2. Replace the line

   ```
   <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
   ```

   in your `php5.conf` by

   ```
   <FilesMatch "\.(ph(p3?|tml)|html?)$">
   ```

   and reload apache by executing the following command:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 reload
   ```

   In addition to the previously mentioned extensions, the new configuration also affects:

   - `.htm`
   - `.html`

Answer (score 1):

is apache running?

when open localhost, you must see "It works!" page.
if apache isn't running, you can use `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`

Maybe php module is not enabled. To enable

```
a2enmod php5
```

after

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

You can use

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

to see the error logs.

Comment: apache is running and the module is enabled. But when i run that tail command i get "[Wed May 16 13:24:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Wed May 16 13:24:30 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed May 16 13:25:25 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.8 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 16 13:25:57 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
"

Comment: the favicon error is weird because that picture file is definitely there.

Comment: do you check permissions?

Comment: the problem is solved so i don't really care. but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must install php module.

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: it's already installed and at the newest version.